# Manual alpha scale exp(-x)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `pp` that contains a variable `nearby_distance` which I would like to be mapped to the `alpha` aes such that a value of `nearby_distance` equaling `0` corresponds to full visibility and a value of `nearby_distance` approaching infinity corresponds to an alpha approaching complete transparency.

I could define a new variable `pp$alphavar <- exp(-pp$nearby_distance)` and use `alphavar` as my `alpha` aes.  This approach would satisfy my needed transformation but the legend shown on the plot would not be in meaningful units. How can I create a manual alpha scale that would accomplish this desired transformation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made sample data frame containing `x`, `y` and `nearby_distance` values.

```
pp<-data.frame(x=1:200,y=1:200,nearby_distance=seq(0,9.95,0.05))
```

There is a possibility to define your own transformations of values in library `scales` if non of existing fit your needs (see `?trans`). So there is no need to do transformations in original data frame. Using transformations, values are transformed and then used in plot and defining of breaks. Then the breaks are backtransformed to make labels in legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

negexp_trans <- function(){
  trans_new('negexp', function(x) exp(-x), function(x) -log(x))
}
```

New transformation in used in `scale_alpha_continuous()` to get plot.

```
ggplot(pp,aes(x,y,alpha=nearby_distance))+geom_point(size=5) + scale_alpha_continuous(trans = 'negexp')
```

[image: example plot with custom alpha scaling]